# ffmpeg failing when using discord.py

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py

I was making a bot with a rickrolling feature. It involves ffmpeg, but it always gives the following error:

```
FFmpeg version SVN-r18639, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --enable-memalign-hack --enable-postproc --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --disable-ffserver --enable-avisynth --enable-pthreads
  libavutil     50. 3. 0 / 50. 3. 0
  libavcodec    52.27. 0 / 52.27. 0
  libavformat   52.32. 0 / 52.32. 0
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
  built on Apr 21 2009 13:44:38, gcc: 4.2.4 (TDM-1 for MinGW)
Input #0, mp3, from 'rick.mp3':
  Duration: 00:03:33.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 192 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 192 kb/s
Expected number for loglevel but found: warning
```

It keeps giving this error even when I switched to a different file, am I doing anything wrong? I'm on Windows python 3.8.2, discord.py 1.6.0. Here is the code section:

```
@bot.command(name="rickroll")
async def rick(ctx, channel: discord.VoiceChannel):
    connection = await channel.connect()
    connection.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("rick.mp3", executable="ffmpeg.exe"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have FFmpeg added to the PATH environment variable. You can find information on how to do that [here](https://github.com/adaptlearning/adapt_authoring/wiki/Installing-FFmpeg).

To connect to a voice channel you need to pass in the channel's id since you cannot mention it within Discord.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

voiceChannel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, id=channel)
await voiceChannel.connect()
```

Now we need to make the connection with the voice client

```py
connection = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
```

So the final code looks like this

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.command(name="rickroll")
async def rick(ctx, channel: int):
    voiceChannel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, id=channel)
    await voiceChannel.connect()
    connection = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    connection.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("rick.mp3"))
```